# Error when running script involving machine name and local network

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, scripting

I'm trying to write a script that takes a machine name as a command line argument and displays a message informing me whether the host is on the local network.

Here's what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
gateway=$(ip route | grep default | cut -d' ' -f3)

if [[ $(ip route get "$1" | grep -q $gateway) ]]; then

echo "$1 is on the local network"

else

echo "$1 is not on the local network"

fi
```

Whenever I run it with my machine name (ubuntu) I get the following output:

```
Error: any valid prefix is expected rather than "ubuntu".
ubuntu is not on the local network
```

I'm not sure what the error means and why I'm getting it, as well as if the script is even doing what it should be doing. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try providing IP address as argument (`$1`) instead of host name.

Comment: Yes providing my IP address seems to work, but I'm looking to be able to provide the host name as an argument instead. How would I be able to do that? @sungtm

Comment: If your host name can be resolved, try `ip route get "$(resolveip <hostname> | grep -oE '[[:digit:]].+')"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

gateway=$(ip route | awk '/default/{print $3}')

if ip route get "$1" | grep -q "$gateway"; then
  echo "$1 is on the local network"
else
  echo "$1 is not on the local network"
fi
```

And then use your IP address.

```
./myscript 192.168.0.100
```

- The ip is what you get fro `ifconfig` or `ip r`
- I'm not sure how you will solve that by using host name.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works but is there a way that I can enter the machine name instead of the IP address as a command line argument?

Comment: The only config file I know is `/etc/hosts` but I'm not sure if editing that file will solve your problem. Well that is not an S.O. question imo, since it is specific to ubuntu?